# How can I integrate $\int_0^1 (1-x^{\frac{1}{q}})^p\, dx$

Tags: calculus

I start with a substitution:
$$\int_0^1 (1-x^{\frac{1}{q}})^p\, dx $$
we let $u = x^{\frac{1}{q}}$ meaning that $du = \frac{x^{q-1}}{q}dx$:
$$ q\int_0^1 (1-u)^pu^{q(1-q)}du $$
Using integration by parts I get:
$$ \int_0^1 (1-u)^pu^{q(1-q)}du = q\left(\left[\frac{u^{q(1-q)} (1-u)^{p+1}}{p+1} \right]_0^1 -\frac{q(1-q)}{p+1}\int_0^1u^{q(1-q)-1}(1-u)^{p+1}du \right) $$
Simplifying:
$$ \int_0^1 (1-u)^pu^{q(1-q)}du =  -\frac{q^2(1-q)}{p+1}\int_0^1u^{q(1-q)-1}(1-u)^{p+1}du $$
I'm currently a bit lost as I feel like this is just going in circles. What should I do thanks!

Comment: You can express it as a sum using the binomial theorem for rational $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: There is a mistake in your calculations: $u = x^{\frac{1}{q}} \implies du = \frac{x^\frac{1-q}{q}}{q}dx$

Then $I = q\int_0^1 (1-u)^pu^{q-1}du = \beta(p+1,q)$.

This is assuming $p+1>0, q>0$.

I am leaving my previous solution with your mistake in the block below

---

> You can use beta integral right after the substitution.

$$ \require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\ q\int_0^1 (1-u)^pu^{q(1-q)}du = q\beta (p+1, q-q^2+1)} $$
This is assuming $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{p+1>0, q-q^2+1>0}$.

Here's a link:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Anybody know how to strikeout mistake using latex?

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13183/316409) for cancelling/striking.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^{1/q})^p dx$$
Let $x=\sin^{2q} t$ so
$$I=2p\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2q-1} t \cos^{2p+1} t~ dt $$
Use $\beta$ function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function
to get
$$I=p \frac{\Gamma(p+1) \Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x=u^q$, $dx=qu^{q-1}du$, so the correct calculation is$$\int_0^1(1-u)^pqu^{q-1}dq=q\operatorname{B}(p+1,\,q)=\frac{q\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q+1)}.$$